# How to display a rectangle over an Image in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, image-processing

I am working on a parking space detection Android application written in Java. How would I go upon displaying a marker or bounding box in each of the empty parking spots of the parking lot image?

The data for the coordinates of each vacant parking space will come from a JSON file and I would display that onto the parking lot image.

The JSON would be something like this where x,y corresponds to the pixels of the image.

```
[ 
 {
  "Space": "001", 
  "Row": "1",
  "x": "1000",
  "y": "500"
 }, 
 {
  "Space": "001", 
  "Row": "1",
  "x": "800",
  "y": "600"
 }
]
```

Here is a sample image of how the bounding box could be displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this should have been a comment but I will suggest you use opencv for android and implement the Mat and MatOfRect class to get a rectangle around the points/pixels

Here is a guide link
https://opencv.org/android/